# Google sheets: Add image or drawing if a cell contains specific text

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Just want to ask if how can I add a shape or drawing (half-shaded shape) if the cell has an exact text.

Is it possible that when I type the letter "t" in the cell, the image/drawing will be visible? Though, I don't think it can be done through a formula, given that the cell on which the image/drawing should be placed is the cell on which the letter "t" should be placed. Is there a way for me to do it via script?

[image: Picture]

**EDIT**

As I applied the solution of [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)), it worked. But, it is only working on one cell. How can I make it work on B5:F6 or other cells?

Here are the script and a sample [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gDvnXUDYN11vBUsytxYUx46DgvzWeuSa5qgHBdzVh0Y/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r  = sheet.getRange("B5").getValues();
  
  if (r == 't'){
    var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(5, 9);
    rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(5, 2));
  }
}
```

Comment: In your situation, how about the following flow? 1. Create a drawing and put it in a cell. 2. When the text of `T` is put to a cell, the drawing is copied to the cell you want to put using OnEdit trigger. By this, I think that your goal can be achieved. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike The drawing is placed on a different cell, am I right? So example, I'm going to put `t` on B5, the drawing will be visible there if ever?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. For example, when the drawing is prepared in a cell "A1" and when you want to put the drawing to the cell "B1", you can copy it using Google Apps Script.

Comment: @Tanaike That seems to be right, but I don't know how to code it via script. Can you help me with this?

Comment: In your goal, you want to replace the text `T` to the image in a cell?

Comment: @Tanaike no. I want to put an image in a cell with the text `t`. More likely covers the letter `t` with the image.

Comment: @Tanaike the shape will cover the text `t` in the cell since on the spreadsheet that I'm working on, I still need to count the letter t, but if I can count the shape and not the letter `t` then it will be fine if the letter will be replaced by an image.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. But I would like to try to understand about your goal. When I could correctly understand about your goal, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanaike but can you teach me how to copy a cell using google script?

Comment: When the image in a cell is copied to other cell, you can do it using [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, you should make use of the `e` event object in order to detect where the edit is being made. Therefore, I suggest you make the following changes to your code:

#### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  let r = e.range.getValue();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && r == "t") {
    let col = e.range.getColumn();
    let row = e.range.getRow();
    sheet.getRange(5,9).copyTo(sheet.getRange(row,col));
  }
}
```

#### Explanation

The above script checks if the edit has been done in the `Sheet1` and if the value of edited cell is `t`. If this condition checks, then by using `getRow` and `getColumn`, it gets the range of the cell and then later places the half-shaded shape in that range.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Apps Script onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).